# Проблема инициализации YMKUserLocationLayer()

Tags: ios, swift, yandexmapkit

При выполнении кода:

```swift
let userLocationLayer = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(with: mapView.mapWindow)
userLocationLayer.setVisibleWithOn(true)
userLocationLayer.isHeadingEnabled = true
userLocationLayer.setObjectListenerWith(self)
```

Появляется следующая ошибка:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layer with ID _location already exists'.

Хотя, создание слоя ранее не выполнялось.

Как можно обойти эту проблему и подписаться к YMKUserLocationObjectListener, для отображения местоположения пользователя?

Пока, получаю координаты через LocationManager, но не хочется делать костыли для отображения его на карте. И тогда надо решить проблему отображения перемещения пользователя на карте, ведь точка будет статичной...

Использую:
 - XCode 11.4.1;
 - YandexMapKit 3.5.0;
 - iOS 13.4.1.

Comment: Демо яндекса, в частности https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo/blob/master/MapKitDemo/UserLocationViewController.swift пробовали запускать?

Answer (score 1):

Расширенны  ответ:
Данная проблема связана с тем что у yandex map kit все объекты имеют ссылочный тип и чтоб добраться до них , нам нужно сохранять ссылку на объект.
Данная ошибка получается за счет создания повторной точки юзера.
Я решил данную проблему путем проверки если ли ссылка уже или нет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена посредством просмотра логов. Выяснилось, что данный код вызывался дважды.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ответ так, чтобы он мог быть полезен другим. Опишите как определить и устранить возникшую проблему.